# Cartopy-Python syntax - multiple objects/countries in one line

Tags: python, cartopy

I'm following this example, [Python Mapping in Matplotlib Cartopy Color One Country](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/88209/python-mapping-in-matplotlib-cartopy-color-one-country). It's fully working with several countries, e.g. USA, France, UK, Japan.

```
for country in countries:
    if country.attributes['adm0_a3'] == 'USA':
        ax.add_geometries(country.geometry, ccrs.PlateCarree(),
                          facecolor='#008744', alpha = 0.5,
                          label=country.attributes['adm0_a3']),

    if country.attributes['adm0_a3'] == 'FRA':
        ax.add_geometries(country.geometry, ccrs.PlateCarree(),
                          facecolor='#008744', alpha = 0.5,
                          label=country.attributes['adm0_a3']),
+ 'GBR'
+ 'JPN'

else:
    ax.add_geometries(country.geometry, ccrs.PlateCarree(),
                      facecolor=('#c4e6ff'),
                      label=country.attributes['adm0_a3'])
```

I'd like to put a list of countries in one line rather than repeating the statements over and over.

I tried:

```
if country.attributes['adm0_a3'] == ['USA', 'FRA', 'GBR', 'JPN']:
```

And `any('USA, 'FRA', 'GBR', 'JPN')`

And `['USA or 'FRA' or 'GBR' or'JPN']`

And a dict:

```
myDict = {'USA', 'FRA', 'GBR', 'JPN'}
if country.attributes['adm0_a3'] == myDict:
```

Obviously, I'm not getting the logic quite right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `in` keyword, something like this:

```py
for country in countries:
    if country.attributes['adm0_a3'] in ['USA', 'FRA', 'GBR', 'JPN']:
        ax.add_geometries(country.geometry, ccrs.PlateCarree(),
                          facecolor=(0, 0, 1),
                          label=country.attributes['adm0_a3'])
    else:
        ax.add_geometries(country.geometry, ccrs.PlateCarree(),
                          facecolor=('#c4e6ff'),
                          label=country.attributes['adm0_a3'])
```

Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Several hours of pain for two letters! :o Thanks.